# Javascript JSON.parse not working

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm a total noob to javascript. This is my first time working with it. I am having some issues turning my JSON string into an object so that I can work with it later on in my code. I am calling JSON.parse on my string, but my code never executes past that line. I have been using alerts as a kind of debugging tool and the code never gets past this line:

```
var toPass = JSON.parse(liveJSON)
```

my JSON looks like this:

```
{"request_list": [{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382410,},{"ip": "192.168.0.18","rtt": 1,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382410,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382410,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382410,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382440,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382440,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382468,"time_executed": 1428382440,},{"ip": "100.43.91.14","rtt": 81,"protocol": "HTTP","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382680,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 141,"protocol": "HTTP","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382680,},{"ip": "10.10.0.119","rtt": 0,"protocol": "HTTP","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382710,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382680,},{"ip": "69.166.54.200","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382680,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_executed": 1428382680,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428382734,"time_exe...,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384030,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384030,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384030,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384060,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384060,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384067,"time_executed": 1428384060,},{"ip": "10.99.0.190","rtt": 0,"protocol": "HTTP","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384180,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384150,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384150,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384150,},{"ip": "69.166.48.102","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384180,},{"ip": "10.3.1.12","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384180,},{"ip": "69.166.49.126","rtt": 0,"protocol": "NAS","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384180,},{"ip": "69.166.54.200","rtt": 0,"protocol": "DB","time_asserted": 1428384201,"time_executed": 1428384150,}]}
```

Comment: It's not a valid JSON. Put it to any JSON validator and see it yourself.

Comment: use online tool :  http://jsonlint.com/  to validate your json

Comment: Yeah, your JSON isn't JSON

Comment: another nice tool to debug json: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'json' data is not valid (but it is valid in javascript)

eg:

```
... "time_executed": 1428384150,}]}
```

the last comma is not allowed in standard JSON

you should use standard JSON library to construct your json string.

somethign invalid in json but valid in javascript:

```
[{},]  
{ {}, }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have trailing `,` after each `"time_executed"` value. Your JSON is not valid.

http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

JSON parser http://json.parser.online.fr/ is also another good site to check if the JSON structure is correct.